# What is this holographic material

Tags: plastic, material-identification

I have some decorations that have standard fairy lights behind some plastic which creates a kind of holographic effect.

There is a similar product here: https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07JB979HD

What is this material and what types of places sell it?

[image: Christmas star holographic light decoration]

Comment: I’m not sure but I defiantly know that it’s not holographic [this is holographic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yr3hE.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called "3D star effect foil" or "3D holographic foil" and can be found in well-equipped craft stores (especially around christmas time) or online:

- [Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Rayher-23009000-star-effect-100x33cm-0-15mm/dp/B013DPINX4)
- [Dannells](https://www.dannells.com/3d-light-scattering-holographic-foil----milky-white---33cm-x-3mtrs-3186-p.asp)

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. I've just ordered some.